# Пишется ли обращение с большой буквы?

Tags: прописная-строчная, обращение

Обращения вроде:

- о, охотник
- о неразумная

и пр. пишутся с большой или с маленькой буквы?

Comment: охотник и неразумная - это имена собственные в Вашем тексте (или клички)?

Answer (score 2):

С прописной буквы пишутся имена, прозвища или псевдонимы людей, клички животных, имена фантастических существ и сказочных персонажей.
Если Охотник и Неразумная относятся к таким категориям, то пишутся с большой буквы (в том числе и при обращении).

Вот известные примеры: Крошечка-Хаврошечка; Шарик и Рыжик; Страшила; Балда; Следопыт и Зверобой (герои романов Фенимора Купера); Трус, Балбес и Бывалый.

Сравните:
*— Здравствуй, Лин, — сказал **О**хотник* (братья Стругацкие. Полдень, XXII век) — прозвище.
*— Здравствуй, Вилли, — сказал **о**хотник* (братья Стругацкие. Возвращение) — профессия.

*— О, неразумная! Я хотела дать бессмертие твоему сыну, сделать его неуязвимым* (Н. Кун. Боги и герои. Мифы Древней Греции).

[Прописная буква в собственных именах и названиях](http://russkay-literatura.ru/pravila-pravopisaniya-russkogo-yazyka/605-propisnaya-bukva-v-sobstvennyx-imenax-i-nazvaniyax.html)

Answer (score 1):

Перечисленные обращения пишутся, как у вас, с маленькой буквы и запятой от ***о*** не отделяются, если ***о*** частица. Отделяются они только в том случае, если ***о*** междометие, в таком случае оно выражает удивление или восхищение и после него делается пауза. Если всё же ***о*** частица, то запятую ставят только после обращения. Подробнее об этих случаях у [Розенталя](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=126), § 27б, п. 6.

Прописная буква в обращениях могла бы иметь место только в том случае, если бы они были прозвищами. Ну или кличками, как подумал Арсений, например собак.